# Powershell - Display richtext data as formatted text without loading external file - WinForms or XAML

Tags: winforms, powershell, xaml, rtf

I have RTF data from a database I need to render as formatted text in a Powershell GUI. Can be either Winforms or XAML.

Trying WinForms, when I load the richtext control's RTF property, and place the it on a form, it STRIPS all formatting. I want to SHOW/Render all formatting.

I dont want to persist thousands of database records to a disk file first, so I can use the LoadFile method here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2

Sample data:
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
{*\generator Riched20 16.0.4639}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\cf1\f0\fs20 At my desk\f1\par
{*\lyncflags}}

Comment: The RTF input provided outputs `*Riched20 16.0.4639At my desk*` using `Segoe UI` as Font. Is this not what you want?

Comment: The .NET Control i was talking about only accepts and lets you apply font changes using a toolbar above the control, that markup gets stored in RTF format. I wanted something to render RTF.